# Can I save some pages of a book in Google Books?

Tags: google-books

I hope to save a few pages of a book freely available at Google Books: Page 218-223 of [Richard Hittleman's Yoga: 28 Day Exercise Plan](http://books.google.com/books?id=8Zh0a2BpqfsC&lpg=PP1&dq=yoga%20richard%20hittleman&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false). I am using Ubuntu and preferably Firefox.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Book Downloader](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/37933)

This is a [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script that works under Firefox. I have tested this under a Windows 7 machine as I don't have access to a Ubuntu machine here with me.

To download a book (or the preview pages you can see) from Google Books

1. Install the [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) add-on to Firefox
2. Install the [Google Book Downloader](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/37933) script (Click on **Install** in the upper right)
3. Go to the Google book you wish to download, in your case [Richard Hittleman's Yoga: 28 Day Exercise Plan](http://books.google.com/books?id=8Zh0a2BpqfsC&lpg=PP1&dq=yoga%20richard%20hittleman&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false)
4. On the left hand side column click **Download this book**, select the **from** and **to** pages
5. Once the images are created of the pages you're allowed to view, you may download them. Currently it's one at a time.

For the current page your viewing there is a download image that looks like a floppy disk with PA### where ### is the current page on the right hand side of the page. Clicking this will allow you to download the single page.

Comment: +1. Thanks! Later I found out that script, but encountered a new problem: when downloading the available pages using some tools in batch mode, because all pages are named the same, it repeatedly asks for manual rewriting or renaming. I wonder if the pages can be renamed according to their actual page numbers, so that the files have different names, can be downloaded automatically and the downloaded files will be more organized? See my question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/407006/batch-downloading-available-pages-in-google-books).

Comment: Note that using "Google Book Downloader", the texts on the links to the available pages have different names named after their page numbers, but the actual files, when downloading, have the same name.

Comment: this script appears not to be available anymore.

Comment: Here's a static mirror of it http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/37933

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the eBook is freely available? If so, it could be country restricted as I don't see it.

Assuming you can access the PDF copy, try opening it in Chrome. Chrome would open the PDF using its native [PDF Viewer](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1060734). With the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+P, you can invoke the Print Dialog box within Chrome. Set the Destination option there to "Print to PDF" & instead of selecting "All" for pages, set the page range that you require.

Alternatively, you can install [CutePDF Writer which can print any document to PDF](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2008/06/how-to-convert-authenticated-protected.html) and then print the range of PDF pages as a new PDF.

Comment: Thanks! The book format is not pdf, but some online format only used by Google.

Comment: Ok, so the book is available for viewing but not download. If there is a "EBook Free" button for any book (like out-of-copyright books mentioned here - http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2006/08/download-classics.html), a download-as-PDF link is available.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Looks like you need to be in US and you only get first 30 pages, therefore your out of luck. Sorry.**

Google only overs a preview if the author has uploaded pages of it and made those available as  preview or if they made it free.

Here is what the page you linked to would look like if you could preview it:

[image]

As you can see your book your looking at has no preview button:

[image]

Therefore you cannot preview the book it's only available for purchase.

Comment: If you look at his link to Google Books, you are shown a preview of the book.

Comment: But look at my image there is no preview of the actual pages inside the book. Yes there is of the front cover but not the contents.

Comment: I'm able to see the first 30 pages of the book from the link Tim provided. I see you're located in Canada and I'm in the US, so that might be why you don't get a preview.

Comment: Probably. Anyway my answer sorta applies. 30 Pages is not enough. OP wants later in the book. Looks like he is out of luck

Comment: Most likely, but since his location is unknown, he may have different rights to view different parts of the book. At my college campus I'm able to access more preview pages of books than when I am at home looking at the same book. This was a while ago though